# How to sum rows by group in a big datafram?

Tags: r

My data (crsp.daily) look roughly like this (the numbers are made up and there are more variables):

```
PERMCO PERMNO date        price    VOL   SHROUT 
103     201    19951006     8.8    100    823
103     203    19951006     7.9    200    1002
1004    10     19951006     5      277    398
2        5     19951110     5.3    NA     579
1003     2     19970303     10     67     NA
1003     1     19970303     11     77     1569
1003     20    19970401     6.7    NA      NA
```

I want to sum VOL and SHROUT by groups defined by PERMCO and date, but leaving the original number of rows unchanged, thus my desired output is the following:

```
PERMCO PERMNO  date        price    VOL   SHROUT  VOL.sum   SHROUT.sum
103     201    19951006     8.8    100    823     300         1825
103     203    19951006     7.9    200    1002    300         1825
1004    10     19951006     5      277    398      277        398
2        5     19951110     5.3    NA     579      NA         579
1003     2     19970303     10     67     NA       21         1569
1003     1     19970303     11     77     1569     21         1569
1003     20    19970401     6.7    NA      NA      NA         NA
```

My data have more than 45 millions of observations, and 8 columns. I have tried using ave:

```
crsp.daily$VOL.sum=ave(crsp.daily$VOL,c("PERMCO","date"),FUN=sum)
```

or sapply:

```
crsp.daily$VOL.sum=sapply(crsp.daily[,"VOL"],ave,crsp.daily$PERMCO,crsp.daily$date)
```

The problem is that it takes an infinite amount of time (like more than 30 min and I still did not see the result). Another thing that I tried was to create a variable called "group" by pasting PERMCO and date like this:

```
crsp.daily$group=paste0(crsp.daily$PERMCO,crsp.daily$date)
```

and then apply ave using crsp.daily$group as groups. This also did not work because from a certain observation on, R did not distinguish anymore the different values of crsp.daily$groups and treated them as a unique group.

The solution of creating the variable "groups" worked on a smaller dataset.

Any advise is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you can use `data.table`, then you can simply write `result <- setDT(crsp.daily)[, c("VOL.sum", "SHROUT.sum") := lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = c("VOL", "SHROUT"), by = .(PERMCO, date)][]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data.table u could use the following code

```
require(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(crsp.daily)
dt[, VOL.sum := sum(VOL), by = list(PERMCO, date)]
```

With the command := u create a new variable (VOL.sum) and group those by PERMCO and date.

Output

```
permco permno date price vol shrout vol.sum
1   103 201 19951006    8.8 100 823 300
2   103 203 19951006    7.9 200 1002    300
3   1004    10  19951006    5.0 277 398 277
4   2   5   19951110    5.3 NA  579 NA
```